# Best method for Populating DataSet from a SQLDataReader

Tags: sql, dataset, sqldatareader

I am working on a DAL that is getting a DataReader Asynchronously.

I would like to write a single method for transforming the DataReader into a DataSet.  It needs to handle different schema so that this one method will handle all of my fetch needs.

P.S. I am populating the SQLDataReader Asynchronously, please don't give answers that are getting rid of the DataReader.

Comment: Was DataSet.Load() no good? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5fd1ahe2.aspx

Comment: Actually I wasn't aware of this option. Can't wait to see how complex the .Net framework will be in version 5 etc

Comment: Either was I, thanks for that Matt!

Comment: Hmm. Might post it as an actual answer so it's more discoverable. ;)

Comment: Ended up ditching this althogether as it is too slow.
I utilise a IConverter interface for each entity which reads the reader into the element directly

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try [DataSet.Load()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5fd1ahe2.aspx). It has several overloads taking an IDataReader.

Comment: Ended up using a DataTable (which has the same method)

Comment: it needs string[] or DataTable[] as third parameter. Is there any way to populate initially empty DataSet with no tables without knowing its schema beforehand? 
It also looks like this solution is partially blocking as DataSet.Load() won't take advantage of ReadAsync() and NextResultAsync() methods of SqlDataReader

Answer (score 15):

[DataTable.load()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.load.aspx) can be used for a generic approach.

```
do {
    var table = new DataTable();
    table.Load(reader);
    dataset.Tables.Add(table);
} while(!reader.IsClosed);
```

Comment: This is the answer to the question asked. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If for some reason the Load method fails, here is a manual way to do it:

```
                    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                    dt = sdr.GetSchemaTable();
                    //dt.Constraints.Clear();
                    //dt.PrimaryKey = null;
                    //dt.BeginLoadData();
                    if (sdr.HasRows)
                    {
                        DataRow row;
                        while (sdr.Read())
                        {
                            row = dt.NewRow();
                            sdr.GetValues(row.ItemArray);
                            dt.Rows.Add(row);
                        }
```

Another way is to use SqlTableAdapter:

```
var adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
adapter.Fill(ds);
```